# Two minor questions about a transcendental number over $\Bbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, pi, transcendental-numbers

I'm now painfully studying abstract algebra. I want to ask two minor questions to clarify my concepts, though they would be somehow silly. We know that $\pi$ is transcendental over $\Bbb Q$, hence $\Bbb Q[\pi]$ is an integral domain, and $\Bbb Q[\pi]\subsetneq\Bbb Q(\pi)$. Then I wonder if there is a field $F^\star$ such that $\Bbb Q(\pi)\subsetneq F^\star\subsetneq \Bbb R$? And is there any relationship between $\Bbb Q(\pi)$ and say, $\Bbb Q(e)$? ($e$ is the Euler constant)

Comment: Since $\pi$ is transcendental you can add an irrational algebraic $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)(\sqrt{2})$ and be sure the field grew more. $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(e)$ are isomorphic by sending $\pi$ to $e$ and rationals to themselves.

Comment: Not silly at all. These are the sorts of questions you should be asking yourself all the time.

Comment: Are you familiar with [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set)?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, I have learnt it before.

Comment: @Eric Well, what do you know about the cardinality of $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ versus $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Noah Schweber: I think of $\Bbb Q(\pi)$ as a quotient field produced by the integer domain $\Bbb Q[\pi]$. Since $\Bbb Q[\pi]\cong\Bbb Q[x]$ in this transcendental case, and I feel that $\Bbb Q[x]$ is countable, because there is a clear way to enumerate it (even though I haven't seriously proved it before), so $\Bbb Q[\pi]$ is countable. This time I'm not so sure that a quotient field produced by a countable integer domain is countable, but I still guess it so. And $\Bbb R$ is uncountable. This is what I think.

Comment: @Eric Yes - in general, any countable-degree extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ will again be countable (this is a good exercise), so e.g. $\mathbb{Q}(\pi,\pi^{1\over 2}, \pi^{1\over 4}, ...)$ will also be  a proper subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Eric Re: cardinality of quotient fields, remember that the quotient field (as a set) is a set of equivalence classes of pairs of elements from the original field. Now, think about the cardinality of $X^2$ versus that of $X$ for an infinite set $X$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)\varsubsetneq\mathbb{Q}\bigl(\sqrt\pi\bigr)\varsubsetneq\mathbb R$.
2. $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)\simeq\mathbb{Q}(e)$.

Comment: +1 First part of this answer  gives more than what is asked. By iterating, that is repeatedly taking square roots, one can get an infinite tower of fields sandwiched between $\mathbf{Q}(\pi)$ and $\mathbf{R}$